# Design pattern that allows to add and remove functionality to an object

Tags: javascript, angularjs

**TL:DR** design pattern for semi-related objects that temporarily modify each-other. functionality is added and then removed.

I am a database developer and am trying to learn some of the newer front end goodies as I like to stay aware of whats going on at different points in the stack. I am not an OOP developer but I have an OK idea of how to look at a problem using objects, but I do not know all of the design patterns and the different scenarios they handle. I am learning AngularJS and I have decided to recreate the boardgame [Small World](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dOXKEGg5EKU) as a way to quickly define my requirements. Here is the scenario I am trying to build a foundation for:

The core of the game has Powers and Races each with a unique way of modifying the rules of the game. These Power/Race combinations are used to conquer Regions for points. These modifications are triggered at different phases in the game:

1. First Turn (**Wealthy**: get 7 points, this only happens once)
2. Start Turn (**Amazons**: get 4 extra tokens)
3. Enter Decline (**Ghouls**: Ghouls can be played like an active race when in decline; **Stout**: when entering decline immediately pick your next race)
4. Conquest (**Commando**: takes 1 fewer tokens to conquer a region)
5. Redeploy (**Amazons**: lose 4 tokens; **Fortress**: Place one fortress on a region you occupy. +1 defense +1 point from this region)
6. End Turn (**Hill**: get 1 more point for being on a hill region; **Orcs**: +1 point for every occupied region you conquered this turn)
7. Multi Player/Totally Unique(**Diplomat**: pick someone you did not attack this turn and they cannot attack you until your next turn)

In addition some regions can be marked as having one or more special attributes:

1. **Mine**: dwarves get +1 point from this region even when in decline
2. **Magic Source**: wizards get +1 point from this region
3. **Underworld**: a race that has the underworld power considers all underworld regions adjacent
4. **Mountain**: takes 1 more token to conquer this region, +1 defense

Throughout the course of a game race/power combinations will come into existence and then die to be replaced by another race/power combination. So you can see that there are many attributes/stats I need to track while some races exist. (e.g. who you attacked this turn is only important for diplomat). Now I could define attributes to handle all of the known scenarios but my goal is to allow new race/powers to be added to my config file and for the game to understand how to handle their rule changes. I came up with the idea of a general object called a Modifier and am organizing my objects like so:

```
{
  event:'endTurn', // the game phase that triggers this modification
  modify:{
     points: 1, //hill power
     strength: -4, // amazon redeploy phase, applied to a gameRace
     strength: -1, // commando conquest phase, applied to a region
     actions:[function(gameState, region, gameRace){
        //use the above three params for conditional logic or more advanced modifiers like diplomat
     }]
  }
}


SWGame // is in charge of game state, phases, input from players
+--+Player[]
|  |
|  +--+GameRace[] // handles interactions between / joining race and power. 
|     |           // players can have one declining race and one active race.
|     |           // the spirited power allows 2 races in decline at once
|     |
|     +--+Race // has 0-n modifiers does not understand any other object
|     |  |
|     |  +---Modifier[]
|     |
|     +--+Power // has 0-n modifiers does not understand any other object
|        |
|        +---Modifier[]
+--+GameMap // handles interctions between GameRaces and Regions
   |
   +--+Region[] // has 0-n modifiers does not understand any other object
      |
      +---Modifier[]
```

The problem I am running into is that some Races modify regions (e.g. Giants: if you occupy a mountain all adjacent regions to the mountain cost 1 fewer tokens to conquer). and I am applying a "strength: -1" modifier to the adjacent regions. then at the and of the turn I have to remove all the modifiers for the giants and then apply the modifiers for the next player and their current race. It is getting really messy tracking who the modifier belongs to and it is starting to become incredibly smelly. Any suggestions on a design pattern that is better suited for this scenario?

Comment: [Decorator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern)?

Comment: @SlightlyCuban I thought of decorator but it is not designed for removing functionality. Or maybe I need to think about the problem in different terms to make it work. If I abandoned the idea of modifying a region and all logic was solely based on where game units are on the map then maybe decorator can work.

Comment: @tryingToGetProgrammingStraight that is why I added the TL;DR. what is solid design pattern for adding and removing functionality from an object. I originally looked at decorator but it is not designed for taking functionality away.

Comment: Funny thing is, I could describe Decorator in Java, but my JS kung-foo is not up to it. The gist: Decorator looks like a Wrapper, so your Decorator interface would have an "undecorate" that returns the wrapped class to remove behavior modifications. That's how I'd do it in Java anyway.

Comment: @SlightlyCuban I will reread decorator. that is exactly how I believe this should work. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

you should look up constructor functions and `object.defineProperty` what i think you should do is create a object to keep track of factors that may carry over like so

```
function example(obj){
    this.strengthEffects = obj.strengthEffects;
    this.healthEffects = obj.healththEffects;
}
```

or better yet

```
function example(obj){
    this.amazon = obj.amazon; //boolean value
    //same idea
}
```

then check them in a constructor function like so

```
function changeRace(new example(myObj));

changeRace(carryOver){
    for (var i in carryOver) {
        this.prop = i;
        this.propVal = carryOver[i];
    }
}
```

with this kind of code, you can use a `object.defineProperty` with a `switch` in it to add/remove points to a certain attribute (special attributes/modifications).

hope this helps.

Comment: I think your first snippet is more inline with what I was thinking. I am hesitant to add properties like "amazon, wealthy, orcs" as Boolean because that means somewhere else I am going to be checking that Boolean and that will likely cause a messy list of dependencies that I am trying to avoid.

Comment: well if i helped you can accept my answer, if there is anything else you need help with specify it or ask another question. im always glad to help (thats what we are here for).

Comment: your answer was definitely useful and I appreciate that you took the time to help me but I am not sure it is the right answer.